# Ignore files for commit but keeping them

Tags: git, gitignore

I've got some 'resource files' that get changed every time we run our script. The files are located in a folder called '`res/`'. Gathering the data the is in all these files takes a while, so I don't want to get rid of them every time I pull, however, I don't want to have to commit them whenever they change. I had them listed in a .gitignore but it seems that I loose them between creating new branches, merging branches back, and pulls.

How can I have git not remove them, but not keep track of them?

Comment: Files matched by `.gitignore` are literally ignored by git completely, so git will not move or delete them (unless you explicitly ask for it by running `git clean -X`). If you're losing those files, there has to be something else that cleans them up, or they've been committed in one of the branches.

Comment: @porneL I think that the files I had disappear, disappeared after I created and checked out a new branch. Not entirely sure, but I notice they were missing after that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

..to prevent Git from tracking changes to them. When you're done, you can use:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

..to have Git track them again. I'm pretty certain this will prevent the files from being overwritten when `git pull` is used, but I'm not 100%.

Source: http://blog.pagebakers.nl/2009/01/29/git-ignoring-changes-in-tracked-files/